# how to set default value if key is not available in dict in ansible play

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am setting fact as dict using host names like below,

```
set_fact:
      processed_hosts: "{{ processed_hosts | default([]) + [dict(host_name=item, result=hostvars[item]['_OS_upgraded'])] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups['reachable_a_hosts'] }}"
```

Its working good when all the host has "_OS_upgraded".

But when task failed in any of the host then "_OS_upgraded" is not set, on that scenario i am getting error when i call this `hostvars[item]['_OS_upgraded']`

so want to set it false by default if that item is not in hostvars,

Can some one let me know how to do that?

Comment: If you want to change anything about your question, please edit the question and don't put the edit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after adding | default(False)

```
set_fact:
      processed_hosts: "{{ processed_hosts | default([]) + [dict(host_name=item, result=hostvars[item]['_OS_upgraded']|default(False))] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups['reachable_a_hosts'] }}"
```